# How to run an aggregate function like SUM on two columns in JPA and display their results?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0

I am new to JPA. So my question should be so simple to some.

Below is the Simple Query in SQL which i would like to convert to JPA. I already have an entity class called `TimeEnt`.

```
SELECT 
     SUM(TimeEntryActualHours) as UnBilledHrs,
     SUM (TimeEntryAmount) as UnbilledAmount
FROM TimeEnt WHERE MatterID = 200
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The JPA Query Language does support aggregates functions in the SELECT clause like AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM and does support multiple *select_expressions* in the SELECT clause, in which case the result is a `List` of `Object` array (`Object[]`). From the JPA specification:

> #### 4.8.1 Result Type of the SELECT Clause
>
> ...
>
> The result type of the SELECT
>   clause is defined by the the result
>   types of the *select_expressions*
>   contained in it. **When multiple
>   *select_expressions* are used in the
>   SELECT clause, the result of the query
>   is of type `Object[]`, and the
>   elements in this result correspond in
>   order to the order of their
>   specification in the SELECT clause
>   and in type to the result types of
>   each of the *select_expressions***.

In other words, the kind of query you mentioned in a comment (and since you didn't provide your entity, I'll base my answer on your example) is supported, no problem. Here is a code sample:

```
String qlString = "SELECT AVG(x.price), SUM(x.stocks) FROM Magazine x WHERE ...";
Query q = em.createQuery(qlString);
Object[] results = (Object[]) q.getSingleResult();

for (Object object : results) {
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - 4.8.1 Result Type of the SELECT Clause
  - 4.8.4 Aggregate Functions in the SELECT Clause

Answer (score 9):

Lets think we have entity called `Product`:

```
final Query sumQuery = entityManager
                    .createQuery("SELECT SUM(p.price), SUM(p.sale) FROM Product p WHERE p.item=:ITEM AND ....");
sumQuery.setParameter("ITEM","t1");

final Object result= sumQuery.getSingleResult(); // Return an array Object with 2 elements, 1st is sum(price) and 2nd is sum(sale).

//If you have multiple rows;
final Query sumQuery = entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT SUM(p.price), SUM(p.sale) FROM Product p WHERE p.item in (" + itemlist
                        + ") AND ....");
// Return a list of arrays, where each array correspond to 1 item (row) in resultset.
final List<IEniqDBEntity> sumEntityList = sumQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [EJB Query Language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbtg.html) specification.

The idiom is very similiar to standard SQL

```
EntityManager em = ...
Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT AVG(x.price) FROM Magazine x");
Number result = (Number) q.getSingleResult ();
```

Regards,

Comment: How would i process the result if there where two fucntions?
EntityManager em = ...
Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT AVG(x.price),SUM (x.stocks) FROM Magazine x");

Comment: Well, I don't if this kind of query is supported by JPA, however, you could always execute two queries for achieving this. Regards.

Comment: I suppose you mean the `Java Persistence Query Language`?