# Does Spring Data JPA have any way to count entites using method name resolving?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

[Spring Data JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) supports counting entities using specifications. But does it have any way to count entities using method name resolving? Let's say I want a method `countByName` to count entities with specific name, just like a method `findByName` to fetch all entities with specific name.

Comment: Please accept one of the answers, YaoFeng. I have tested Spring Data JPA 1.5.2 and the countByName() syntax works as Abel notes.

Answer (score 345):

As of **Spring Data 1.7.1.RELEASE** you can do it with two different ways,

1. The *new way*, using query derivation for both count and delete queries. Read [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts), (Example 5).
   Example,

```
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
        long countByName(String name);
    }
```

2. The *old way*, Using `@Query` annotation.
   Example,

```
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
        @Query("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u WHERE u.name=?1")
        long aMethodNameOrSomething(String name);
    }
```

or using `@Param` annotation also,

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM User u WHERE u.name=:name")
    long aMethodNameOrSomething(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Check also [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520827/use-queryhint-when-using-jpaspecificationexecutor/48541323#48541323).

Comment: what about other aggregate functions such as sum, average?

Comment: The question was about the count function, not sum or average. Spring data does not support something like the 'new way' for this functions yet. You could use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449719/how-to-run-an-aggregate-function-like-sum-on-two-columns-in-jpa-and-display-thei)

Comment: In your second and third examples, I think you would need to use "SELECT COUNT(u)...", since this is supposed to be a count query.

Comment: Not to wrorry, found it - commons-lang

Comment: I'll add `Long countByNameIn(List<String> names);` if that can help others, when counting different values

Comment: Didn't work for me with MariaDB until I changed the query string to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE u.name=:name` does (using asterisk).

Database error was: `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'u' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 37):

As long as you do not use 1.4 version, you can use explicit annotation:

example:

```
@Query("select count(e) from Product e where e.area.code = ?1")
long countByAreaCode(String code);
```

Comment: note that the method should return `long` instead of `int`, otherwise you will get a ClassCastException without any clues

Answer (score 19):

JpaRepository also extends QueryByExampleExecutor. So you don't even need to define custom methods on your interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    // no need of custom method
}
```

And then query like:

```
User probe = new User();
u.setName = "John";
long count = repo.count(Example.of(probe));
```

Comment: This version I like most - especially since I couldn't make a clue how this should work according to the docu :-) You saved my day :-) As a remark: Primitives (e.g. int) are included in the expamle-search, i.e. `int age` will be included although not set, but `Integer age` will be excluded from the sample (at least in Eclipselink)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Working example

```
@Repository
public interface TenantRepository extends JpaRepository< Tenant, Long > {
    List<Tenant>findByTenantName(String tenantName,Pageable pageRequest);
    long countByTenantName(String tenantName);
}
```

Calling from DAO layer

```
@Override
public long countByTenantName(String tenantName) {
    return repository.countByTenantName(tenantName);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This feature has been added in version 1.4 M1

Answer (score 6):

According to Abel, after the version 1.4 (tested in version 1.4.3.RELEASE) is possible doing this way:

public long countByName(String name);

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it is implemented now [DATAJPA-231](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-231)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks you all! Now it's work. [DATAJPA-231](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-231)

It will be nice if was possible to create count…By… methods just like find…By ones. Example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   public Long /*or BigInteger */ countByActiveTrue();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping("/user/count")
private Long getNumberOfUsers(){
    return userRepository.count();
}
```

Comment: This example is out of topic. The user asked how to countBy field name and not how to call the basic count from a REST service.

Answer (score 1):

I have only been working with it for a few weeks but I don't believe that this is strictly possible however you should be able to get the same effect with a little more effort; just write the query yourself and annotate the method name.  It's probably not much simpler than writing the method yourself but it is cleaner in my opinion.

Edit: it is now possible according to [DATAJPA-231](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-231)

Answer (score 1):

According to the issue [DATAJPA-231](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-231) the feature is not implemented yet.

Comment: Now it's implemented

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to get the count based on multiple conditions than here is a sample custom query

```
@Query("select count(sl) from SlUrl sl where sl.user =?1 And sl.creationDate between ?2 And ?3")
    long countUrlsBetweenDates(User user, Date date1, Date date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the other solutions do not answer the question. According to the sentence

> Spring Data JPA supports counting entities using specifications.

he wants to use JPA Specifications with name resolving. All the answers are pointing to the api without specifications.

As long as I know there is no repository implementation with specification and name resolving. The JpaSpecificationExecutor does not support it.

I had the same problem and created a custom repository where I used code like:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<S> root = query.from(domainClass);
Path<Object> attribute = root.get(attributeName);
query.select(builder.countDistinct(attribute));

if(spec == null){
    return em.createQuery(query);
}

Predicate predicate = spec.toPredicate(root, query, builder);

if(predicate != null){
    query.where(predicate);
}

return em.createQuery(query);
```

The variable "attributeName" is a String with the name of the attribute.