# how to retrieve an aggregation function query with spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data jpa 1.2 and I can't find anyway to retrieve an aggregate query result like the following one.

```
select count(v), date(v.createTimestamp) from UserEntity v
    group by date(v.createTimestamp)
```

Which work perfectly with the native JPA

```
@Entity()
public class UserEntity {

   @Id
   private long id;
   .
   .
   @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
   private Timestamp createTimestamp;

}
```

any my JPA repository is

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>, 
      JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserEntity> {
}
```

so how can I do an aggregate queries throw Spring data, I find absolutely nothing in the documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way to do this

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>, 
      JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserEntity> {

      @Query(value = "select count(v), date(v.createTimestamp) from UserEntity v group by date(v.createTimestamp)", 
             countQuery = "select count(1) from (select count(1) from UserEntity v group by date(v.createTimestamp)) z")
      public List<Object[]> findCountPerDay();
}
```

This way we can get aggregate data along with actual count ( aggregated records )

Answer (score 5):

"countBy" is currently not supported in Spring Data:

[Support to 'countBy' query methods](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-231)

[Does Spring Data JPA have any way to count entites using method name resolving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696490/does-spring-data-jpa-have-any-way-to-count-entites-using-method-name-resolving)

Comment: The second you list actually has been updated to reflect that as of spring data 1.7, the countby predicate has been added

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `@NativeQuery` option

Answer (score 0):

You can have **@Query** for custom queries for your **unsupporeted** methods in spring-data.