# @Query annotation is not reading native sql select * spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface ConsumerRepository extends CrudRepository<Consumer, Long>  {

    List<Consumer> findByLastName(String lastName);
    List<Consumer> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    //List<Consumer> readExistsFirstName(String firstName);
    //List<Consumer> getByFirstNameAndLastNameOrderByFirstName();
    //Collection<Consumer> findById(Long id);
    @Query("select c from Consumer as c where c.firstName like '%?1%'")
    Collection<Consumer> findByNameContains(String word);

    @Query(value = "SELECT ppc_consumer FROM ppc_consumer WHERE lastname = ?1",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM ppc_consumer WHERE lastname = ?1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Consumer> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
 }
```

**But is shows error " Distinc expected " , got * because i have used * inside @Query annotation ? what is wrong please ?**

Comment: Why do you want to use native query here ? You can actually fetch the  ppc_consumer records directly, right ? Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: @developer your asking me a question ? i need answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it as below example-

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM consumer WHERE lastname = :lastName  LIMIT :maxRecord", nativeQuery = true)
StickerProduct findWalletProduct(@Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("maxRecord") Long maxRecord);
```

Another way to do same instead of * :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM consumer c WHERE lastname = :lastName  LIMIT :maxRecord", nativeQuery = true)
StickerProduct findWalletProduct(@Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("maxRecord") Long maxRecord);
```

I Hope it work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't use * in spring jpa you have to use aliases. Try this way:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ppc FROM ppc_consumer ppc WHERE ppc.lastname = ?1",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(ppc) FROM ppc_consumer ppc WHERE ppc.lastname = ?1")
```

See this question for more information

[Does Spring Data JPA have any way to count entites using method name resolving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696490/does-spring-data-jpa-have-any-way-to-count-entites-using-method-name-resolving)

Comment: it is because of the `nativeQuery=true` command. I edit the answer, i tried removing that and it works for me.

Comment: your example is also perfectly working but you could also add * example :)