# Why does my DAO class in hibernate contain no entities?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

First I will say while this app runs, it is broken in what I want to test. I basically want to display all the saved entities from MySql via hibernate and print it out in web browser with thyme leaf. I can not figure out what am I doing wrong. No exceptions but the DAO.count show as 0. Thanks for any help.

DAO:

```
@Repository("CustomerDAO")
@Transactional
public interface CustomerDAO extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

    public List<Customer> findAll();
    public long count();
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class CustomerController {


    private CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerDAO(CustomerDAO customerDAO) {
        this.customerDAO = customerDAO;
    }

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listCustomers(Model model){
        long test = customerDAO.count();
        model.addAttribute("answer", test);

        List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Customer(){}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Html/thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h3 th:text="${answer}"></h3>
<div th:each="customer: ${customers}">
<h3 th:text="${customer.firstName}">This didnt work</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=metalgear3
spring.datasouce.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
entitymanager.packagesToScan = com.luv2code.entity.Customer
```

Print Trace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-04-22 15:22:48.047  INFO 1640 --- [           main] com.luv2code.App                         : Starting App on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 1640 (/Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/JavaProjects/target/classes started by ronaldpitt in /Users/ronaldpitt/Desktop/JavaProjects)
2017-04-22 15:22:48.050  INFO 1640 --- [           main] com.luv2code.App                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-22 15:22:48.334  INFO 1640 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sat Apr 22 15:22:48 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-22 15:22:49.932  INFO 1640 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36008335] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-22 15:22:50.374  INFO 1640 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-22 15:22:50.403  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-22 15:22:50.404  INFO 1640 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-04-22 15:22:50.567  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-22 15:22:50.567  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2237 ms
2017-04-22 15:22:50.765  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-22 15:22:50.771  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 15:22:50.772  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 15:22:50.772  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 15:22:50.773  INFO 1640 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-22 15:22:51.672  INFO 1640 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-22 15:22:51.703  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-04-22 15:22:51.825  INFO 1640 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
2017-04-22 15:22:51.827  INFO 1640 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-04-22 15:22:52.021  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-04-22 15:22:52.159  INFO 1640 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-04-22 15:22:52.846  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@73041b7d'
2017-04-22 15:22:52.851  INFO 1640 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-04-22 15:22:53.529  INFO 1640 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@77be656f: startup date [Sat Apr 22 15:22:48 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-22 15:22:53.633  INFO 1640 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.luv2code.controller.CustomerController.listCustomers(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2017-04-22 15:22:53.639  INFO 1640 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-04-22 15:22:53.639  INFO 1640 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-04-22 15:22:53.687  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-22 15:22:53.687  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-22 15:22:53.756  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-22 15:22:54.578  INFO 1640 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-22 15:22:54.683  INFO 1640 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-22 15:22:54.692  INFO 1640 --- [           main] com.luv2code.App                         : Started App in 17.286 seconds (JVM running for 17.954)
2017-04-22 15:22:56.968  INFO 1640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-04-22 15:22:56.968  INFO 1640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-04-22 15:22:56.997  INFO 1640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 29 ms
2017-04-22 15:22:57.170  INFO 1640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: What exception or error message do you get? If there is an exception, please post the stack trace.

Comment: No exceptions but the DAO.count show as 0

Comment: Are you sure there are some rows in `customer` table when the application is running? Hibernate should display on the console the SQL queries it runs: do they yield anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27458590/6743203

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy, yes the rows display in my GUI (workbench). I've just posted the print trace incase.

Comment: @JaySmith thank you but the count works, I'm trying to figure out why the count is empty and there is no list displaying.

Comment: Maybe you need to fill in database. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_importing_script_files