# Counting the Number of Rows That Have a Spesific Value in a Column in a Table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
id | street | city | country | postal code |
--------------------------------------------
0  |a street|x city| Turkey  | 12345       | 
1  |b street|y city| Turkey  | 12335       | 
2  |c street|z city| USA     | 12315       | 
3  |d street|j city| Turkey  | 32345       | 
4  |e street|k city| Germany | 12135       | 
5  |f street|l city| France  | 13215       | 
6  |g street|m city| Turkey  | 42135       | 
7  |h street|n city| Italy   | 12135       | 
8  |i street|z city| Spain   | 32115       |
```

Hello. Let say we have a table like above named 'person_address'. In db there are lots of different tables like this. I want to find the number of rows whose values are "Turkey" in the "country" column in the person_address table which is 4. How can I translate this into postgresql?

```
SELECT * FROM person_address u WHERE u.country = 'Turkey';
```

With this code i can list what i want but i need number of that list. And after that i have to use this in Java spring boot project. Should to this with @Query annotation or is there a better way?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696490/does-spring-data-jpa-have-any-way-to-count-entites-using-method-name-resolving

Comment: Hint:  `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the output you want, you will get the answer very quickly. The following query returns the countries that have been listed 4 times.

```
select *
from
   (select *,
        count(*) over(partition by country order by country) as numberOfCountry
    from person_address) t
where numberOfCountry = 4
```