# Spring JPA - How to count number of Foreign key

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to make a simple book organizing app with Java Spring.

**I have attached an image at the bottom of the page.
Add the number of works as in the webpage.**

It has an author entity and a book title entity.
The author entity has a one-to-many relationship with the title entity of the book.

//Author entity

1 auther_id <-primary key

2 auther_name

3 birthplace

//Book title entity

1 title_id <-primary key

2 title_name

3 auther_id <-foreign key

Display it as a table in html. Then, create a number of works column for each author.
For example, there are 3 Shakespeare books. Therefore, I would like to display "3" in the number of works column.
How can I do it?

AutherRepository.java

```
 @Repository
 public interface AutherRepository extends JpaRepository <AutherEntity, Long> {
 }
```

BookTitleRepository.java

```
 @Repository
 public interface AutherRepository extends JpaRepository <BookTitleEntity, Long> {
    public long countByAuther_id(long auther_id);
 }
```

BookService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BookService {
   @Autowired
   private AutherRepository autherRepository;
   private BookTitleRepository booktitleRepository;

   Long countByAuther_id(long auther_id);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7uZ9.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696490/does-spring-data-jpa-have-any-way-to-count-entites-using-method-name-resolving

Comment: I checked the URL, but it did not solve the problem.
I wrote the code halfway through, but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

In the author entity:

```
//the mappedBy is the name of the variable at Book entity
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Book> books;
```

In the book entity:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Author author;
```

Then you can always call the size of the books prop of author like this:

```
Author author1 = authorRepository.findById(author_id);
author1.books().size // <----- here it is what you want
```

Comment: Vocês me ajudaram a resolver este problema!
Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz que deu certo!