# MAX of a SUM in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA and I'm stuck on a query. I have on my system the class Consumer, which has Orders in a many to one relationship, one consumer can have several orders or any, and a order must have a consumer mandatory. Order has an attribute called totalPrice, which is the total amount of the order.

I'm trying to fetch the consumer who has spent more money. I need to do the sum of their orders and then the max, so first, I have tried this to get the max:

```
select max(sum(o.totalPrice)) from Order o group by Order.consumer
```

But JPA doesn't support the max(sum(... Also, it doesn´t support any sub-query on FROM clause or "LIMIT" clause at the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might get your answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449719/how-to-run-an-aggregate-function-like-sum-on-two-columns-in-jpa-and-display-thei or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624807/using-sum-in-hibernate-criteria

Comment: Are you sure it's not an error in your query? You have not defined `o` so `o.totalPrice` doesn't exist.

Comment: LIMIT clause is SQL. JPQL supports setMaxResults/setFirstResult which does the same thing ... unless you're referring to those on a subquery.

Comment: @Deltharis yes, you are right, it was just a typing mistake, i didnt ctrl + C ctrl + V, i typed it. But its right on my test enviorement.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved by myself. I have used "ALL" operator. Thanks.

Comment: How did you used the "ALL" operator?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a two-level grouping. First you calculate the sum per consumer, second you want the max over all consumers. Easiest would be to calculate the sum per consumer in a sql statement, then order by the sum and retrieve the first row.

But mind if you have lots of consumers and orders (which in a real life system i suppose you have) such a select statement always is a full table scan of consumers and orders. Usually this is critical in performance. Maybe its prefereable to precalculate the sum in its own entity (a reporting entity) by some timer job or whenever you enter a new order.