# sum of rows after group by in query dsl or jpql

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, querydsl

I am trying to sum rows of table after group by, let me explain my problem with an example:

1) I need to calculate total expenses by name, dept. I can do this with group by, simple and easy.

by name:

```
select e.Employee_name, sum(expenses) 
from Employee e 
group by Employee_name
```

by dept:

```
select e.dept, sum(expenses) 
from Employee e 
group by dept
```

This is where I am struggling with JPA.

2) I need to calculate total expenses when grouped by name  or dept. 
with native SQL I can do inner query in from clause like below:

```
select sum(employeeExpense) 
from (
   select e.Employee_name, sum(expenses) as employeeExpense 
   from Employee e 
   group by Employee_name
 ) X
```

I am stuck with step 2 to solve that problem using Jpa , is there a way to do this in jpa or query dsl ?

[image]

Comment: you can use createQuery and it will return to you what you want and it will return to you object [] or object according to your query so take a look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449719/how-to-run-an-aggregate-function-like-sum-on-two-columns-in-jpa-and-display-thei

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: corrected my query.

Answer (score 0):

so I will give you just one query approach here 
use createquery and it will return to you something like that

```
select e.Employee name , sum(expenses) 
from Employee e 
group by Employee name

@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
List<Object[]> list =    em.createQuery("select e.EmployeeName , sum(e.exprenses) from Employee e group  by e.EmployeeName").getResultList();
```

each of list element is Object[] and Object[] have first element will be employee name and second one is will be sum(exprenses)

Comment: i am looking for jpql version of query in step 2 in my question.

Comment: second step just take all employee expenses summary why do you do ,just take all of them with select sum() from table, it will work select sum(expenses) from employee it will give you all employee expenses summary

Comment: sorry if i am not clear, i need to calculate total expenses after group by.i need total expenses grouped by employee name and dept. makes sense ?